# How do I inject a static method call into a symfony service?

Tags: php, symfony, protocol-buffers, grpc

I want to turn this into a service:

```
        $grpcClient = new MyGrpcClient($_ENV['GRPC_HOST'], [
            'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        ]);
```

I tried this:

```
    MyNamespace\MyGrpcClient:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $hostname: '127.0.0.1:44001'
            $opts: ['@Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()']
```

But it doesn't work.

```
    The service "MyNamespace\MyGrpcClient" has a dependency on a non-existent service "Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure()".
```

Comment: Lookup factories in the service container documentation.

Comment: @Cerad OK. that makes sense, except that it must be an associative array. And as far as I can tell, there's no way to do associative arrays in symfony services? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ideas from @Jeroen van der Laan, and @Cerad I was able to come up with a solution:

```
<?php

namespace App\Proto;

use MyNamespace\MyGrpcClient;
use Grpc\ChannelCredentials;

class GrpcClientFactory
{
    public static function create()
    {
        return new MyGrpcClient($_ENV['GRPC_HOST'], [
            'credentials' => ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
// services.yml
    MyNamespace\MyGrpcClient:
        public: true
        factory: ['App\Proto\GrpcClientFactory', 'create']
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern).

```php
namespace Foo\Bar;

class MyGrpcClientAdapter
{
    private $grpcClient;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->grpcClient = new MyGrpcClient($_ENV['GRPC_HOST'], [
            'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
        ]);
    }

    public function doSomethingAdaptive(): void
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Which can be configured to lazy load into the Symfony container by using:

```yaml
Foo\Bar\MyGrpcClientAdapter:
    class: 'Foo\Bar\MyGrpcClientAdapter'
```

You can refactor the adapter to use configurable (host) values like so:

```php
public function __construct(string $host)
{
    $this->grpcClient = new MyGrpcClient($host], [
        'credentials' => \Grpc\ChannelCredentials::createInsecure(),
    ]);
}
```

Passing (for example) a `.env` value.

```yaml
Foo\Bar\MyGrpcClientAdapter:
    class: 'Foo\Bar\MyGrpcClientAdapter'
    arguments:
        - '%env(APP_HOSTNAME)%'
```

Comment: I started down this path, but I don't want a wrapper for the generated class. I just wanted it instantiated a certain way. But thanks to your inspiration, I came up with a solution that works for what I need.